# STM32F446 on board temperature sensors,the timer configuration problem

Tags: embedded, stm32f4discovery

i am currently try to ramp up bare metal programming using STM32F446 nucleo board.
I try to make use of on board temperature sensors and display the value on via UART.
i studied the code from http://www.microdigitaled.com/ARM/STM_ARM/Code/Ver1/Chapter07/Program7-2.txt
I not really understand timer code,i understand register configuration but i don't get why does it needed in this case, are  the timer try to tabulate the sensors value for every one second?

Comment: The purpose of the timer in this example is described in the comments.  What is not clear.  Include the relevant code in the question - off site links may not be maintained.

Comment: Off-topic, that code is pretty smelly. Register setup code should use meaningful constants, not just a bunch of magic numbers that forces the reader of the code to sit with their nose stuck in the manual. Such code is just marginally better than reading the raw binary op codes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described in the code comments:

```
ADC1->CR2 = 0x13000000;
```

Configures the ADC conversion to be triggered from TIM2, then,

```
while(!(ADC1->SR & 2)) {}
```

"busy-waits" for a single conversion to complete.